# extended pdo connection returns null

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, connection, extends

I have a problem. I have 2 classes (RouteController and BaseController). In the class BaseController i have my pdo connection included, and working. And in the class RouteController i have extend the BaseController and i want that the connection also works in the RouteController class. But if i make a var_dump() it returns NULL. How do i can make that it works?

Index.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'App/Config.php';
require_once 'App/Controllers/BaseController.php';
require_once 'App/Controllers/RouteController.php';
require_once 'App/Controllers/DatabaseController.php';

$connection = new DatabaseController($config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['pass'], $config['database']['name']);
$connection = $connection->Connection();

new BaseController($connection);
new RouteController;
```

Here are the classes:

DatabaseController

```
<?php

class DatabaseController
{
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $name;

  public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $name)
  {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function Connection()
  {
    try {
      $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->name, $this->user, $this->pass);
      $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $this->db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
      return $this->db;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

BaseController

```
<?php

class BaseController
{
  protected $connection;

  public function __construct($connection)
  {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }
}
```

RouteController

```
<?php

class RouteController extends BaseController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    var_dump($this->connection); // Return NULL
  }
}
```

I need some help please, thanks.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: php doesn't call constructors in parent classes automatically. you have to call them yourself, e.g. `function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
<?php

class RouteController extends BaseController
{
  public function __construct($connection)
  {
    parent::__construct($connection);
    var_dump($this->connection); // Return NULL
  }
}

$myObject = new RouteController($con);
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php 

class BaseController
{
  private $connection;

  public function __construct($connection)
  {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  public function getConnection() {
      return $this->connection;
  }
}

class RouteController extends BaseController
{
  public function __construct($connection)
  {
    parent::__construct($connection);
    /* some other construct code */
  }
}

$test = 'hello';
$myObject = new RouteController($test);
var_dump($myObject->getConnection());
```

this work

Comment: That doesnt work, because now $connection is a undefined variable

Comment: you are sending the $connection when you create the object and when you are doing the `parent::__construct($connection);` you are passing the connection to the parent construct function.

Comment: Look, i updated the thread and added my index.php there i have the connection.

Comment: i updated my answer with a test code, try it please.

Comment: I works, but so i need to make for every controller a new database connection. thats why i have make the class BaseController because there is the connection and than in the other controllers i want to extends the class.

Comment: Then you would to create all you needed connections and then pass in the parameter each one of them. If you like, you can add a create method in the __construct and pass the parameters to create the connection

Comment: glad to help you friend, if you need anything else more, you can say